# How to do conditional rendering in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am developing an App which can be used to create tasks and bin them inside lists to track them efficiently.I have created the lists and the tasks inside the lists.

I am trying to render all the tasks that belong to a list inside the list. But, when I write the vue code for that I am facing a problem. Instead of rendering the tasks that only belong to that list, my code generates all the tasks that is inside the database. Can somebody help me find the right way to render only the tasks that belong inside a particular list.

`DashboardView.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div class="dashboard">
    <Navbar class="navbar__dash" />
    <h1 class="dashboard__welcome">Welcome {{ name }}</h1>
    <div class="listview">
      <div class="no__lists" v-if="len_list === 0">
        <h2 class="no_lists">There are No lists here tap to add</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="has__lists" v-else>
        <div class="all__lists" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
          <div class="list">
            <div class="title">
              <div class="title__options">
                <h1 class="list_name">{{ item[0].list_name }}</h1>
                <Dropdown />
                <!-- V-menu -->
                <!--menu ends-->
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
              <div class="no_tasks" v-if="item[0].no_of_tasks === 0">
                <h3>There are no tasks added yet</h3>
                <router-link
                  class="createList"
                  :to="`/createTask/${id}/${item[0].list_id}`"
                >
                  <fa class="list_plus" icon="fa-solid fa-plus" />
                </router-link>
              </div>
              <div class="has_tasks" v-else>
                <h4>Here are your tasks</h4>
                <div class="tasks" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
                  <div
                    class="tasksforthis"
                    v-for="(task, index1) in item[1]"
                    :key="index1"
                  >
                    <div
                      class="filtered__tasks"
                      v-if:="`{{ item[0].list_id }} == {{ task.list_id }}`"
                    ></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <router-link
                  class="createList"
                  :to="`/createTask/${id}/${item[0].list_id}`"
                >
                  <fa class="list_plus" icon="fa-solid fa-plus" />
                </router-link>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
              Number of Completed tasks: {{ item[0].no_completed }}/{{
                item[0].no_of_tasks
              }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <router-link :to="`/createList/${id}`">
        <fa class="plus__icon" icon="fa-solid fa-plus" />
      </router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import Dropdown from '@/components/DropdownList.vue';
import Navbar from '../components/NavBar.vue';
export default {
  name: 'DashboardView',
  data() {
    return {
      name: localStorage['name'],
      len_list: 0,
      items: [],
      id: localStorage['id'],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getTrackers() {
      const path = 'http://localhost:5000/dashboard/' + localStorage['id'];
      axios
        .get(path)
        .then((res) => {
          this.items = res.data.list;
          this.len_list = res.data.list[0][0]['len_list'];
          console.log(res.data.list);
          for (let i = 0; i < res.data.list.length; i++) {
            console.log(res.data.list[i][1]);
            for (let j = 0; j < res.data.list[i][1].length; j++) {
              if (
                res.data.list[i][1][j]['list_id'] ==
                res.data.list[i][0]['list_id']
              ) {
                console.log(res.data.list[i][1][j]['title']);
                console.log(res.data.list[i][0]['list_id']);
              }
            }
          }
        })

        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });

      console.log(this.items);
    },
  },
  components: {
    Navbar,
    Dropdown,
  },
  created() {
    this.getTrackers();
  },
};
</script>
```

I receive the data in dashboard through JSON format. An example data can be:

[image]

My code is currently rendering like this:
[image]

But I want the todo list to have GO and Amaterasu tasks, Heisenberg should only display GO, New and AK tasks etc. I.E i only want the lists to render the tasks that only it contains.
If somebody could tell me how to render it properly it will be very useful for me.

Comment: 230 lines of code here, do you mind narrowing it down a bit with only the relevant parts?

Comment: I have trimmed down the code to point its javascript and template.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this block of code

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" class="tasks">
    <div v-for="(task, index1) in item[1]" :key="index1" class="tasksforthis">
      <div
        class="filtered__tasks"
        v-if:="`{{ item[0].list_id }} == {{ task.list_id }}`"
      ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

the first v-for is cycling through each of your items (you are already doing this with the v-for above on div with class="all__lists" to display your list cards) and the second is cycling though each of their tasks.

remove the first v-for like below

```html
<template>
  <div v-else class="has_tasks">
    <h4>Here are your tasks</h4>
    <div v-for="(task, index1) in item[1]" :key="index1" class="tasksforthis">
      <div
        class="filtered__tasks"
        v-if:="`{{ item[0].list_id }} == {{ task.list_id }}`"
      ></div>
    </div>
    <router-link
      class="createList"
      :to="`/createTask/${id}/${item[0].list_id}`"
    >
      <fa class="list_plus" icon="fa-solid fa-plus" />
    </router-link>
  </div>
</template>
```